# Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and trying to include various JavaScript files in my theme's templates. The file which causes the error is the very last js file which is included but I still get this error. Could I get some help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image-cycle").cycle();
});
```

the error is thrown at the very first line - but the script is loaded well after jQuery.

Comment: And the code throwing the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress uses jQuery's noconflict mode by default. This means you always have to wrap your code in a DOM ready handler that will map jQuery to the dollarsign, otherwise the dollarsign will be undefined, like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#image-cycle").cycle();
});
```

[**The codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: It worked! Thanks, learning the process of wordpress can be confusing.

Comment: @Titus Read this to understand: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include Jquery.
Check if u have put put the script tags properly and closed them.
You might have put the src of jquery but the tags might be wrong.